# How to register click action for NSStatusBarButton?

Tags: swift, cocoa

My menu works just fine I just want to be notified when it is clicked to update information inside of it.  However, my statusBarButtonClicked function is never triggered when I click on my status bar button.   How do I send a click event to it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!

let log = SwiftyBeaver.self

let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu

    if let button = statusItem.button {
        button.target = self
        button.action = #selector(self.statusBarButtonClicked(sender:))
        button.sendAction(on: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseUp)
    }
}

@objc func statusBarButtonClicked(sender: NSStatusBarButton) {
    log.info("Status menu clicked")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the action doesn't work if the menu is set. Set the delegate of the menu and implement `NSMenuDelegate` method

```
func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu)
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears thats the source of the problem.  However I just created a ghetto hack to get around it.